# Помогите разобраться с is(':first-child');

Tags: jquery, javascript

подскажите где я ошибаюсь

```
<div class="catalog_menu"><ul><li class=""><a class="beg_level" href="7"   rel="noreferrer">сплит системы</a><div class="submenu" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="8" rel="noreferrer">samsung</a></li>
</ul>
</div></li>
<li class=""><a class="beg_level" href="9" rel="noreferrer">промышленные сплит              системы</a><div class="submenu" style="margin-left: 242px; display: none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="10" rel="noreferrer">mitsubishu</a></li>

</ul>
</div></li>
</ul></div>
```

далее js:

```
if($('.catalog_menu').find('ul').find(this).is(":first-child"))
```

Comment: Зачем вы ищете this, если оно уже известно?

Comment: Более того в методе find нет необходимости в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

для начала уберите '`find(this)`' как уже говорили, далее попоробуйте код в консоли
`$('.catalog_menu').find('ul')` - вы получаете массив из 3х элементов `ul` и после этого пытаетесь выяснить если он первый из числа подобных, т.е. из таких же массивов получается. 
Возможно ошибусь, но мне кажется что вы хотите что-либо сделать с первым элементом списка в каждом `div` класса `catalog_menu`, т.е. видимо нечто такое

`$('.catalog_menu').find('ul:eq(0)')` .. далее уже приделывайте нужные манипуляции с этим элементом или его внутренностями

Comment: Для чего такие чудеса, не проще ли:

    $('.catalog_menu ul').eq(n). ... ?

 

Comment: никаких чудес, документация и обсуждение скорости обработки 
обычного селектора против, селектора с использованием 'find', читал в нескольких местах, что 'find' быстрей чем просто селектор из нескольких элементов - т.е. не проще, а банальная практика

линк на бенчмарк

http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again/11